# Scientifically is fate pre-written?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Thermodynamics state that when a event will start and when will it end! Kinetics define how quick the process will end will it forever or finish within blink of eye is kinetically pre-defined. **Provided,** conditions remain unchanged and process remain undisturbed by external agent.

Taking it on life we are being processed we took birth we shall die is unchanging truth! How we live the life depends on us but as we are in the system(here system could be loclized to person level or globalized to universe I am taking globalized system) we cannot really alter the the kinetics so can it be assumed at least a globalized process is pre-written?

Comment: "Pre-written" and "fate" implies an agency that planned ahead of time. Deterministic physics only describe that from a starting point, each future state is unambiguously going to happen. Physics does not imply that anything or anyone can know what will happen ahead of time or planned for events to happen in a certain way. For the question it would be better to avoid those words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to be careful not to confuse two separate questions:

1. whether every event in the universe is fully determined by the antecedent events that combined to cause it;
2. whether, if that is true, it must follow that we cannot have free will, and so cannot be responsible for anything we do.

These were burning questions in the first two thirds of the last century, often summarised into whether scientific determinism, if true, entails the absence of free will.  If what we do just happens to us as a result of processes that precede even our births, can we really say we can ever 'help it'?  Can 'our' actions really be ours?

Notice, that the question itself presupposes the truth of determinism.  It was thought in the 1950s and 1960's by British philosophers, such as P.F.Strawson, that this question about the logical relationship between scientific determinism and freedom of will and therefore moral responsibility for our actions involved a confusion about what is meant by 'freedom of will'.  The point, it was argued, was that we speak of 'freedom of will' in contrast to circumstances in which we are prevented from doing as we choose, or compelled to do what we do not want to do by other people or states or laws. Whether we are free or not has nothing whatever to do with causality.  Indeed we do not think of ourselves as 'causing' our actions.  We just perform them.

As to the question of scientific determinism itself, you have do make a further distinction:  between whether everything that happens is the inevitable result of an infinitely wide network of preceding events or whether there are elements of chance involved.  The most obvious reason for thinking so involves the field of quantum physics, in which up to now it seems that predictions are at least to some extent probabilistic, even though the mathematics works pretty well in general. Ironically, prediction seems at its most successful at the largest cosmic scales.  As to how individual humans are going to behave in the future, I am afraid we seem no better placed today, with all the triumphs of science behind us, than people were when the populist politician, Julius Caesar became consul in BCE 59.

Answer (score 1):

The universe is either deterministic or it is not. Not deterministic means there are sources of random so that there are multiple ways the future could happen.

If so, due to chaos theory, even tiny events can change the future in big ways.

Science and physics typically describe a model of nature that is deterministic, but without philosophic claims about whether nature is deterministic.
For building space rockets or skyscrapers the philosophical nature of the universe being deterministic or not does not matter usually, because in engineering even deterministic sources of noise need to be handled and those are usually just as bad as random sources.

So it's not valid to assume that just because a physics book describes physical processes in a deterministic way that physics claims the universe is deterministic. It's just deterministic enough in any case to describe processes like that usefully enough for most engineering purposes.

On the quantum level, processes are not described so deterministically.

Even if the universe behave deterministically, that does not imply that anything or anyone can reliably predict the whole future, let alone that anyone or anything could have set up starting conditions to achieve a certain result. If I am led with closed eyes to a darts board, given a darts arrow, and throw the arrow in the direction of the dartboard, the final position of the dart might be deterministic, but that does not mean I knew where it would land or that I intended to put it there. So "fate" and "pre-written" are unsuitable words in the question given the full question description.

Comment: You’re right to say that we don’t know whether the Universe is deterministic, but since seemingly-random phenomena such as radioactive decay still follow statistical distributions it is reasonable to assume that these result from deterministic principles and laws that we don’t know about.  If that weren’t the case, if we attempt to measure, for example, the half-life of an isotope we would not see the value converge with an increasing sample size.

Comment: @Frog can we say there are too many variable in our requisite function that even slightest change (butterfly effect) can change everything.moreoveer variable are in themselves interdependent and a few of them are based the output of function itself

Comment: @Ha’Penny in reality the calculations that would be necessary to predict the future would require a supercomputer capable of modelling the entire universe with complete accuracy.  Since the computer itself must necessarily be a part of the universe thus can never be brought about, so even if the universe is deterministic we can’t demonstrate it.

Comment: The butterfly effect does not depend on how many variables are in a function. It depends only on how variables impact the end result. A function with just one variable can behave chaotically. The butterfly effect itself alone did not prevent 1000% predictability. Only if there are also possible errors in measurement the problem arises because we cannot do 99% accurate predictions anymore if there is chaos in the function.